# How to merge cells of row in table in latex?

Tags: latex, tabular, multirow, multicol

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UONsE.png)
For example i have this table from excel which i want to add in latex. I am trying but ot able  to sucesfully manage to do this. any lead to this will great help to me.

I tried using multirow in latex but actually did not work.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}       & \multicolumn{3}{c|} {\textbf{97\%}}& \multicolumn{3}{c|} {\textbf{146\%}}& \multicolumn{3}{c|} {\textbf{244\%}}\\
  \cline{3-5}
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                      & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation\\
  \hline
  CCTV Display & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  CCTV Recorder & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  VCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  BCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  TCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  PECU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  OBCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 1  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 2  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 3  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 4  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 5  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 6  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please show the code of your table without the merged cells.

Comment: Here is an easy example of a table with merged cells: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71388603/2777074

Comment: \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
       Parameter & Ports & Switch 1 & Switch 2 & Switch 3 & Switch 4 & Switch 5 & Switch 6  \\ \hline
        Bandwidth Utilisation (Percentage) & Port 1 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 25 & 20  \\ \hline
        Bandwidth Utilisation (Percentage) & Port 2 & 25 & 20 & 23 & 25 & 25 & 25  \\ \hline
        Bandwidth Utilisation (Percentage) & Port  3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{table

Comment: I was not able to use multi row I was getting some error

Comment: Can you please add the code to your question? As you might have noticed, comments don't properly display code.

Comment: I have added the code and how can I resize so that it fits my document text width

Comment: To use `\multirow` you need `\usepackage{multirow}`.

Comment: Yes I have put that command already in my document settings. I just not able to make proper columns and rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a professional looking table, I suggest the following layout:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{some caption text}
\begin{tblr}{
  cells={halign=c,valign=m}, 
  colspec={@{}X[1.3,halign=l]XXXXXXXXX@{}},
  colsep={3pt}
}
  \toprule
  Increase in Data Volume & \SetCell[c=3]{} 97\% &&& \SetCell[c=3]{} 146\% &&& \SetCell[c=3]{} 244\% &&\\
  \cmidrule[r]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[l]{8-10}
  Parameter & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation\\
  \midrule
  CCTV Display & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  CCTV Recorder & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0   & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  VCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  BCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  TCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  PECU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  OBCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 1  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 2  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 3  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 4  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 5  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 6  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However it leaves a bit space on top of my page. How can I start table from top of the page if starting in newpage.

Comment: I tried using vspace but it only makes table up not the caption.

Comment: @SanchitJain Please ask a new question including a [mre] about the spacing at the top. The code from my answer will add the table exactly at the start of the text area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYJAX.png

Comment: Hi seems like i can post one question in 90 minutes. I am adding answer to my question which I want to ask.

Comment: @SanchitJain Please don't. Answers should be reserved to what it says: answers

Comment: Ok sure! One last thing since u have used margins 1cm, since it changes my university layout. So I didn't use that command. but now Channel utilisation and bandwidth utilisation words are merging with each other. Hw can I adjust the column width for these two columns.

Comment: @SanchitJain You did not post a [mre] so I can't test to find a solution which fits your page layout.

Comment: Yeah Its bit hard to explain without image. Maybe I will post in 90 minutes. But thanks a lot for the code. That solved my 90% of the problem.

Comment: I have posted. could you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74403946/how-to-fix-the-overlapping-words-in-table-latex