# How to fix the overlapping words in table latex?

Tags: latex, tabular

[image]

```
  \documentclass[twoside = false, % doppelseitiger Druck
    DIV=17,                
    BCOR=15mm,              
    chapterprefix=false,
    headinclude=true,
    footinclude=false,
    pagesize,              
    fontsize=11pt,          
    paper=a4,               
    bibliography=totoc,    
    index=totoc,            
    cleardoublepage=plain, 
     headings=big,          
    listof=flat,            
    numbers=noenddot
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,sc]{mathpazo} 
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Comparison of Different Traffic conditions}
\small
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={@{}X[2]XXXXXXXXX@{}},
  cells={halign=c,valign=m}, 
  colsep={3pt}
}
  \toprule
  Increase in Data Volume (Percentage) & \SetCell[c=3]{} 97\% &&& \SetCell[c=3]{} 146\% &&& \SetCell[c=3]{} 244\% &&\\
  \cmidrule[r]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[l]{8-10}
  Parameter & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation & Latency       & Channel Utilisation       & Bandwidth Utilisation\\
  \midrule
  CCTV Display & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  CCTV Recorder & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0   & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  VCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  BCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  TCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  PECU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  OBCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 1  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 2  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 3  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 4  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 5  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 6  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
```

How can I adjust these words so that they does not overlap for example bandwidth utilisation and latency.

Basically I tried adjusting margins but i dont want to adjust margin for whole document.
\end{document}

Comment: If you ask about a specific problem with the table with, we really need to know how wide your table is. Please don't only post a code fragment, make a compilable [mre]!

Comment: I have also no idea how wide my table is. I am just using my university layout. I am extremely new in latex and want to write my thesis.

Comment: That's why we need to see a reproducible example.

Comment: Shall I also write my document formatting settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options:

- you could rotate the table and show it in landscape format
- use an even smaller font
- refrain from giving redundant information, e.g. the first cell does not need to specify that the values are in percent if your numbers are all followed by percent signs.
- use abbreviations in the header to fit them in the available space. You can explain the abbreviations in the captions if they aren't clear:

```
  \documentclass[twoside = false, % doppelseitiger Druck
    DIV=17,                
    BCOR=15mm,              
    chapterprefix=false,
    headinclude=true,
    footinclude=false,
    pagesize,              
    fontsize=11pt,          
    paper=a4,               
    bibliography=totoc,    
    index=totoc,            
    cleardoublepage=plain, 
     headings=big,          
    listof=flat,            
    numbers=noenddot
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,sc]{mathpazo} 

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Comparison of Different Traffic conditions}
\begin{tblr}{
  cells={halign=c,valign=m}, 
  colspec={@{}X[1.7,halign=l]XXXXXXXXX@{}},
  colsep={2.5pt}
}
  \toprule
  Increase in Data Volume & \SetCell[c=3]{} 97\% &&& \SetCell[c=3]{} 146\% &&& \SetCell[c=3]{} 244\% &&\\
  \cmidrule[r]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[l]{8-10}
  Parameter & Latency       & Ch. Util.       & Band. Util. & Latency       & Ch. Util.       & Band. Util. & Latency       & Ch. Util.       & Band. Util.\\
  \midrule
  CCTV Display & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  CCTV Recorder & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0   & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  VCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  BCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  TCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  PECU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  OBCU & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 1  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 2  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 3  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 4  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 5  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  Switch 6  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0    & 0& 0    & 0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]